# Why is the output resistance of a CMOS inverter determined by the NMOS when the output is high but by the PMOS when the output is low?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, resistance, cmos

For the output pulled high, my professor's slides give this diagram:
[image]

and the equation

$$
r_{DSN} = \frac{1}{k_n'\left( \frac{W}{L} \right )_n \left(V_{DD} - V_{tn}\right)}
$$

and for the output pulled low, there's a similar diagram, except that the gates are connected to ground instead of \$V_{DD}\$ and the resistance equation is the same except that the \$n\$'s are replaced with \$p\$'s.

This seems backwards to me though.  If I understand correctly, the PMOS is the pull-up network and the NMOS the pull-down.  So I would've thought that, when the output is high (i.e. pulled-up), the resistance is determined by the PMOS and vice versa.  Why is it actually the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your thought is correct. It is probably a typo in your professor's slide. In the (c) diagram you have in your question, output V0 = 0 i.e., the output is pulled low.